# Visual Studio cannot find referenced Assemblies after starting with Admin privileges

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In my C# solution, I have references to some dlls which are accessed via network. If I run Visual Studio with Admin-privileges, the namespace of these dlls cannot be resolved any more.

This seems not to be a problem with rights. I can start my explorer as admin and have access to these files.

What could be wrong?

Comment: without admin privileges does it works fine?

Comment: Yes. Everything's working as expected without admin rights.

Comment: How does the reference path look? Is it a mapped drive?

Comment: Yes, it is a mapped drive.

Comment: tried it but it works fine with network location and admin privilege. I doubt that the network drive is share with your current logged in user and not the admin user of your system..le me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well... I don't get it. My current user is an admin-account (member of admin-group) and has these mapped drives. When running VS with admin-privileges, these mapped drives are gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, as Ashutosh Singh suggested, that running VSTO as Administrator changes the account which is running VSTO, even if my logged in account is in the local admin group and other programms do not behave this way. Therefore my mapped drives were gone.

My quick and dirty solution: Open the File->Open->Project dialog und create the network mapping.

This wasn't too easy to figure out in my case, because my local admin account and my logged in domain account coincidentally had exactly the same name :)